How can perform load testing in a website which is developed in Aura component in salesforce
How can perform load testing in a website which is developed in Aura component in salesforce.
I tried Test script Recorder to record the session and while executing all the details are recorded propely.
Tried Test Script Recorder and Blazemeter recorder.

What is your requirement?  What is your performance SLA with Salesforce?  Have you coordinate with Salesforce for any Performance test that touches their infrastructure (they have to approve your plan, your scripts, your test destination, your test window, etc...)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you're able to replay recorded test without any issues (I would suggest inspecting responses using View Results Tree listener just in case to ensure that your script is doing what it is supposed to be doing)

Perform parameterization of your test (credentials, test data, etc), normally people go for CSV Data Set Config for this
Make sure that JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser
Add virtual users according to your workload model
Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode
Generate HTML Reporting Dashboard and analyze test results

